# How to apply technical indicators to a list of stocks

Tags: r, lapply, quantstrat, technical-indicator

I am trying to apply MACD and RSI technical indicators to the adjusted prices of a list of stocks. The end goal of the code is to generate a buy/sell signal for each stock based on the 2 indicators. However, I am having trouble applying the indicators using the lapply function. I'll appreciate all your help. Thanks!

```
#Load Packages
    library(quantstrat) 

#Initialise Settings
    start.date <- "2016-01-01"
    end.date <- as.character(Sys.Date())

#Stock Tickers
    tickers <- c("JPM", #JP Morgan
    "FB", #Facebook
    "SPY", #S&P 500
    "AMZN", #Amazon
    "WMT", #Wal-Mart
    "LVMUY", #LVMH
    "MCD", #Mac Donald's
    "BMW", #BMW
    "KO", #Coca-Cola
    "G13.SI", #Genting Sg
    "Z74.SI" #Singtel   
    )

#Retrieving Stock Data
    options("getSymbols.yahoo.warning"=FALSE)
    suppressMessages(getSymbols(Symbols = tickers, from = start.date, to = end.date, src = "yahoo", adjust = TRUE))

#Grouping Adjusted Prices
    AdjPrices <- do.call(merge, lapply(tickers, function(x) Ad(get(x))))

#Apply MACD Indicator
    MACD <- lapply(AdjPrices, MACD, list(AdjPrices, nFast =12, nSlow = 26, nSig = 9))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
MACD <- lapply(AdjPrices, FUN = MACD, nFast =12, nSlow = 26, nSig = 9)
```

Maybe you ultimately want something like this?

```
    z <- do.call(merge, lapply(AdjPrices, function(x, nFast, nSlow, nSig) {
        y <- MACD(x, nFast, nSlow, nSig) 
        colnames(y) <- paste0(colnames(y),".", gsub(pattern = ".Adjusted", replacement = "", x = colnames(x)))
        y
        }, nFast = 12, nSlow = 26, nSig = 9))

> tail(z)
            macd.JPM signal.JPM   macd.FB signal.FB  macd.SPY signal.SPY
2017-06-23 0.5439033  0.2746984 0.7333757 0.6242897 0.4931503  0.5617852
2017-06-26 0.5628315  0.3323250 0.7378923 0.6470103 0.4735852  0.5441452
2017-06-27 0.6455863  0.3949773 0.5754388 0.6326960 0.3884193  0.5130000
2017-06-28 0.8647098  0.4889238 0.5809413 0.6223450 0.3883060  0.4880612
2017-06-29 1.1460891  0.6203568 0.4633677 0.5905496 0.3134080  0.4531306
2017-06-30 1.3738249  0.7710504 0.3627919 0.5449980 0.2656285  0.4156302
```

Edit, additional explanation of what is going on:

In the above lapply function call, an anonymous function is defined (this bit: `function(x, nFast, nSlow, nSig) { ..... }`), which computes the MACD for a ticker, and then renames the columns.  Note that this function has no "name", or put another way, the function is not assigned to a variable (writing this code assigns a function to a variable in R, e.g. `use_macd <- function() {}` )

The above code is equivalent to the following (more verbose) code, where we explicitly define the function that lapply will call, and then the results are combined with `do.call(merge ....`)

```
use_MACD <- function(x, nFast, nSlow, nSig) {
               y <- MACD(x, nFast, nSlow, nSig) 
               colnames(y) <- paste0(colnames(y),".", gsub(pattern = ".Adjusted", replacement = "", x = colnames(x)))
               y
}


tickerLst <- lapply(AdjPrices, FUN = use_MACD, nFast = 12, nSlow = 26, nSig = 9)
# Now have a list of "macd" values for each ticker.

#Combine into one xts object:
z <- do.call(merge, tickerLst)
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply and thank you for your help once again. Could you kindly explain to me how does your code work? And to answer your question, yes, I would ultimately like for it to look this. In addition, I would like to include the RSI indicator and then generate buy/sell signals if both the indicators' criteria are met.

Comment: What is unclear about this code and I will expand? You've used these functions in your question in the first place (like do.call etc) so not sure what is unclear to you.

Comment: Could you explain to me the role of the square brackets {} in the do.call function? Thanks!